# Test simple_form custom inputs with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, simple-form

I wonder if anyone has tried to test a simple_form custom input with rspec,

I've been looking at the simple_form tests but I can't seem to find a proper way to user their helpers with rspec.

Thank you,

Comment: A custom simple_form input isn't all that special, it's just a wrapper around a builder instance that spits out a form field. By the time your test executes, your field has been rendered and you can use it's ID to select it like you would any normal form element with Capybara. Do you have some code to post with a specific problem?

Comment: I want to test the outputted html, without going throw render_viewes in a controller, test the input in isolation

Comment: My personal recommendation would be to leave the view testing for integration tests. Unit Testing views is a long walk for a short drink of water. But good luck, I hope you get an answer that helps.

Comment: This is rather complex input, it's composed out of several hidden_fields and a couple of inputs, I will fell much better if I could test things with ease. Simple regex on the html will do but I can't find a way to isolate it.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the input code